# Insert textarea after each textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the html

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" />
<input type="text" id="textbox3" />
<input type="text" id="textbox4" />
<a href="#" id="change">Change</a>
<a href="#" id="change1">Change1</a>
```

We are below code

```
var textbox = $("input[type='text']");
var textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea' rows='10' cols='35'></textarea>");
$("#change").click(function () {

    $("input[type='text']").each(function( index ) {
      $(this).hide();
      $(textarea).insertAfter(this);
    });
});

$("#change1").click(function () {

    $('textarea').remove();
    $("input[type='text']").show();

});
```

Comment: So what's the problem? **Also `id` to any element in html must be unique**

Comment: Hope you would be expecting **[`this`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6u9vhp78/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to user `$()` selector for plain HTML like `<textarea id='textarea' rows='10' cols='35'></textarea>` and also wrong usage of `insertAfter`, in your case is better to use `.after`. Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scm8h9wm/) with solution.

```js
var textbox = $("input[type='text']");
var textarea = "<textarea id='textarea' rows='10' cols='35'></textarea>";
$("#change").click(function () {

    $("input[type='text']").each(function( index ) {
    $(this).after(textarea);
      $(this).hide();
      
    });
});

$("#change1").click(function () {

    $('textarea').remove();
    $("input[type='text']").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<a href="#" id="change">Change</a>
<a href="#" id="change1">Change1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are not using textarea id in your code, you can remove it

```
var textarea = $("<textarea rows='10' cols='35'></textarea>");
```

since as @guruprasadrao has pointed out, id has to be unique.

secondly when user clicks on change again you might not want to keep adding textareas again, so change it to

```
$("#change").click(function () {

    $("input[type='text']").each(function( index ) {
      if ( $(this).next().attr( "type" ) != "text" )
      {
         $(this).next().remove();
      }
      $(textarea).insertAfter(this);
      $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to iterate through each input .Directly use:

```
$("#change").click(function () {
  $("input[type='text']").after($(textarea));
});
```